# Code Reduction in Delete Function for Doubly Linked-List

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

```
void delete(struct node **top,int val)    
{       
    struct node *cur=(*top);    
    while(cur!=NULL&&(cur)->data!=val) 
    {   
        cur=cur->next;    
        if(cur==(*top))   
        { 
            if((*top)->next!=NULL)    
            {   
                (*top)=(*top)->next;   
                (*top)->prev=NULL;   
            }   
            else   
                (*top)=NULL;   
        }
        else   
        {    
            cur->prev->next=cur->next;    
            if(cur->next!=NULL)    
                cur->next->prev=cur->prev;    
        }
        free(cur);    
        printf("deleted %d \n",val);    
    }
}
```

**My question is:**

Is there any way to reduce my code in doublely linked-list `delete` function?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation, not shorter but you can check differences. Also much more clean. p is head, g is tail node.

```
void Container::Remove(int pr)
{
    Node *pDel = p; Node *pNex = p->next;
    while (pDel != NULL){
        if (pDel->item.GetValue() > pr){
            if (p == NULL || pDel == NULL) return;
            if (p == pDel) p = pDel->next;
            if (g == pDel) g = pDel->prev;
            if (pDel->next != NULL)
                pDel->next->prev = pDel->prev;
            if (pDel->prev != NULL)
                pDel->prev->next = pDel->next;
            delete pDel;
        }
        pDel = pNex;
        if(pDel != NULL) pNex = pDel->next;
    }
}
```